# Windows 8 Credential Provider: Linking RFID to an account

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, credential-providers

I made a Windows 8 credential provider. Once the users gets close with the RFID they are allowed to login without typing a username and password. The authentication information is currently linked via a plain text file. It stores the tuple (rfid, username, userpassword). This is not safe and meant to be a temporary solution for a proof of concept.

How do I safely link the the RFID and the account using the windows 8 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiously you use a database for your application. Save your data in a table of the db (which in any case is more efficient approach) and query the DB for each RFID read:

```
CREATE TABLE [Users](
    [RFID]     [nchar(24)] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Isadmin] [bit] NULL
)

Select Username,Password from Users where RIFD='TagRead'
```

Comment: There is a lack of information on doing this with the windows framework online. I'm starting to believe this is the only approach. My only concern is I don't want to save plain text passwords even in my own DB. A hash password in my DB would not match what Windows has.

Comment: This ultimately is what I did. However since this is a part of a bigger application that does not include a db I simply serialize the data to a file and encrypt it.